# How to keep the listview and mapview inside scrollview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mapview

First of all, I know it's not good to keep the mapview or listview inside the scrollview. But i wish to design the page like the following.

I tried `setListViewHeightBasedOnchildren` method. It is sluggish as my listview is dynamic. The mapview, I can't scroll up and down and it's flickering when i am scrolling.

What is the best way to do this?

Can i add all the view as my listview header? The mapview is heavy!! Can i add that view as header to the listview?

[image]

Here is the source code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_menu" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/topMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/top_menu" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomMenu"
    android:layout_below="@id/topMenu"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="20dip"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearShopInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Images and its header -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgStoreImage"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="165dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_border"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- style="@style/CustomRatingBar" -->

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingShops"
                    style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtReviewCount"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chkFavoriteShop"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@drawable/icon_star_empty"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/favorite_store" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtConnect"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/share"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnFaceBook"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_twitter" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_google_plus" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_share" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAboutStoreCaption"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/about_the_store"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAboutStore"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMapAndLocationCaption"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/map_and_location"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mMapFrame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dip" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mMapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShopAddress"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/coupons"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="3dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtShopWebAddress"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_mouse"
                android:drawablePadding="4dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/view_website"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:background="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtShopNumber"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_phone"
                android:drawablePadding="4dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linOffers"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRewards"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
                    android:paddingTop="12dip"
                    android:text="@string/rewards"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDeals"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
                    android:paddingTop="12dip"
                    android:text="@string/deals"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCoupons"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
                    android:paddingTop="12dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/coupons"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtGiftCards"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey_deep_dark"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
                    android:paddingTop="12dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/gift_cards"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRewardBalance"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/offerList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="20dip"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linGiftCards"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGiftCardBalance"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAddToCard"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_full_size"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="@string/add_to_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGiveAGiftCard"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_full_size"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_gift_card"
                android:drawablePadding="6dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="30dip"
                android:paddingRight="30dip"
                android:text="@string/give_a_gift_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoOffersAvail"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do not use listview inside scrollview.. I suggest you to use linearlayout and inflate item in it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441594/how-to-add-same-view-to-parent-multiple-times-by-inflating-it-only-once

Comment: @Ketan Ahir Thanks for the hint. What if i have large list? Will it work smoothly?]

Comment: @RethinavelPillai ketan is saying right