# Cannot add several chips into ChipGroup

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to add chips into ChipGroup(not singleLine):

```
val chip = Chip(this)
    chip.isCloseIconVisible = true
    for (i in 0..10) {
        chip.setText("Some text $i")
        chip_group.addView(chip as View)
    }
```

But I get an exception:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

How can I mark chip as a unique child? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add the same view more than once to parent.

Refer this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032857

It throws the above mentioned exception.

You are trying to add the same Chip to the parent more than once.

Try modified code like,

```
    for (i in 0..10) {
        val chip = Chip(this)
        chip.isCloseIconVisible = true
        chip.setText("Some text $i")
        chip_group.addView(chip as View)
    }
```

Comment: You were right. But why? I am using the same context in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare chip inside for loop

```
for (i in 0..10) {
    val chip = Chip(this)
    chip.isCloseIconVisible = true
    chip.setText("Some text $i")
    chip_group.addView(chip as View)
}
```

Since you declare it as a `val` (which means not changed it is value), you are getting the same child error.